# React input to filter to chart. How convert a hardcoded number into a variable?

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-hooks, chart.js

I have created in React a filter to show my data in a chart. The filter and the chart are working well but only when i manually hardcode the value to be filtered.
The problem is that now when i wanted to include an input field and a submit button to have a dynamic chart, it does not work.

The problem is related to the number 9 being hardcoded. The aim is to change it to a variable that can be submitted in the frontend:

```
const filterData = myChart.data.datasets[0].data.filter(value => value > 9)
```

I have tried different solutions such as to create a new variable, or to add the target.value, among others, however nothing worked.

The code VerticalBar.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import faker from 'faker';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Chart',
    },
  },
};

const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
const ctx = null;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, ({
  data: {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: ['10', '9', '15', '7', '13', '8', '20'],
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 235, 0.5)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)',
        'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)',
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -20, max: 20 })),
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(25, 9, 13, 0.2)',
      ],
      borderColor: 'rgb(53, 162, 235)',
      BorderWidth: 10 
    },
  ],
}
}
))

export default function VerticalBar() {
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");
  const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState("");
  const textChangeHandler = (i) => {
    setEnteredText(i.target.value);
    console.log("target.value", i.target.value);
  };

  const filterChart = () => {
    const filterData = myChart.data.datasets[0].data.filter(value => value > 9)
    console.log("filterData y", filterData)
    const filterLabels = [];
    const filterColors = [];
    let i = 0;
    for (i; i < filterData.length; i++) {
      const result = myChart.data.datasets[0].data.indexOf(filterData[i]);
      const labelsresult = myChart.data.labels[result];
      const colorsresult = myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[result]
      filterLabels.push(labelsresult);
      filterColors.push(colorsresult);
    }
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = filterData;
    myChart.data.labels = filterLabels;
    myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = filterColors;
  }
  filterChart();

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setDisplayText(enteredText);
    const x = enteredText;
    console.log(x);
    setEnteredText("");
  };


  return (
    <div>
    <Bar options={options} data={myChart.data} />
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Get user input</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Box component="form" sx={{'& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },}} noValidate autoComplete="off" >
      <TextField  placeholder="type something"
          type="number"
          value={enteredText}
          onChange={textChangeHandler} id="outlined-basic" label="Number" variant="outlined" />
    </Box>
        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" endIcon={<SendIcon />}>
          Submit
       </Button>
      </form>
      <p>You just typed: {displayText}</p>
    </div>
    <hr></hr>
    </div>
  )
  }
```

Comment: what do you get when you check this?
 'const filterData = myChart.data.datasets[0].data.map(value => console.log(value) )'

Comment: @Gregfan i get the data: 10 9 15 7 13 8 20

Comment: @Gregfan can you please clarify what sort of solution would you suggest?

Comment: Instead of your hardcoded "9" are you trying to use the value from the text input? Did you remember to convert from string to number?

Comment: Yes exactly.  Would you have any suggestion in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `filterChart` method you just need to accept a parameter that the inputted number is. Then you can filter against it like so:

```js
const textChangeHandler = (i) => {
  setEnteredText(i.target.value);
  console.log("target.value", i.target.value);
  filterChart(Number(i.target.value)); // Call filter after entering value
};

const filterChart = (filterVal = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER) => { // Expect value to filter against, default to lowest safe integer to show all data
  const filterData = myChart.data.datasets[0].data.filter(value => value > filterVal) // Filter against value
  console.log("filterData y", filterData)
  const filterLabels = [];
  const filterColors = [];
  let i = 0;
  for (i; i < filterData.length; i++) {
    const result = myChart.data.datasets[0].data.indexOf(filterData[i]);
    data.datasets[0].data.indexOf(filterData[i]);
    const labelsresult = myChart.data.labels[result];
    const colorsresult = myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[result]
    filterLabels.push(labelsresult);
    filterColors.push(colorsresult);
  }
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data = filterData;
  myChart.data.labels = filterLabels;
  myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = filterColors;
}
```

Also if you are using `react-chartjs` you dont need to make a chart object yourself, you are only wasting memory usage with that

Comment: even though it works now, i lost the correct indexing of the filtered values with the addition of the "filterVal". I have tried several ways to solve it without success. Do you have any idea how to solve the filtering with the correct indexing?